# How to change options based on another select option in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML. I try to keep it as simple as possible.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <select class="category">
     <option value="low">Low</option>
     <option value="mid">Mid</option>
     <option value="high">High</option>
    </select>
   </td>
   <td>
    <select class="details">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <select class="category">
      <option value="low">Low</option>
      <option value="mid">Mid</option>
      <option value="high">High</option>
     </select>
   </td>
   <td>
    <select class="details">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

How to show options(class="details") on the first row based on logic (low=1-2, mid=3-4, high=5-6) and select first option(class="details") without changing options(class="details") on the others row?

I have tried this

```
$('.category').on('change',function(){
    switch ($(this).val()){
        case 'low':
            $('.details option').each(function(){
                if (+$(this).val() < 3 ) {
                    $(this).show();
                    $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
                } else $(this).hide();
            });
        break;
        case 'mid':
            $('.details option').each(function(){
                if (+$(this).val() < 5 && +$(this).val() > 2) {
                    $(this).show();  
                    $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
                } else $(this).hide();
            });
        break;
        case 'high':
            $('.details option').each(function(){
                if (+$(this).val() > 4 ) {
                    $(this).show();  
                    $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
                } else $(this).hide();
            });
        break;
        case '':
            $('.details option').show();
            $('.details option:first').prop('selected', true);
        break;
    }
});
```

But every time I change others row category, it changes every option (class=" details") on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `$('.details option')` so it will get all details options and loop for all. So instead of using `$('.details option')` use this `$(this).closest('tr').find('.details option')`

The `closest` will only return selected `category` details options and loop only for that not for all.

**DEMO**

```js
$('.category').on('change', function() {
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case 'low':
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.details option').each(function() {
        if (+$(this).val() < 3) {
          $(this).show();
          $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
        } else $(this).hide();
      });
      break;
    case 'mid':
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.details option').each(function() {
        if (+$(this).val() < 5 && +$(this).val() > 2) {
          $(this).show();
          $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
        } else $(this).hide();
      });
      break;
    case 'high':
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.details option').each(function() {
        if (+$(this).val() > 4) {
          $(this).show();
          $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
        } else $(this).hide();
      });
      break;
    case '':
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.details option').show();
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.details option:first').prop('selected', true);
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="category">
          <option value="low">Low</option>
          <option value="mid">Mid</option>
          <option value="high">High</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="details">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="category">
          <option value="low">Low</option>
          <option value="mid">Mid</option>
          <option value="high">High</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="details">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works well except the options not reset if I change category so after if statement I just add $(this).closest('tr'),find('.details options:first') just as you said

Comment: @ghabriel yes you can also change inside of loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is select only the options in the same row by using the jQuery [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function

Change the code
`$('.details option')` to `$(this).closest('tr').find('.details option')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but I think this is...

```js
$('.category').on('change',function(){
    var option  = $(this).data('option');
    var value   = $(this).val();
    var details = $('select.details[data-option="'+option+'"]');

  switch( value ) {
     case 'low':
        details.html(`
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        `);
       break;
       
       case 'mid':
        details.html(`
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        `);
       break;
       
       case 'high':
        details.html(`
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        `);
       break;
    }
});
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <select class="category" data-option="1">
     <option value="low">Low</option>
     <option value="mid">Mid</option>
     <option value="high">High</option>
    </select>
   </td>
   <td>
    <select class="details" data-option="1">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <select class="category" data-option="2">
      <option value="low">Low</option>
      <option value="mid">Mid</option>
      <option value="high">High</option>
     </select>
   </td>
   <td>
    <select class="details" data-option="2">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/vgtbz950/)**

I suggest the use of `hide` class instead, what gives you the ability to select the first option simply like :

```js
$('.category').on('change', function() {
  var detail = $(this).closest('tr').find('.details');

  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case 'low':
      detail.find('option').each(function() {
        if (+$(this).val() < 3) {
          $(this).removeClass('hide');
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('hide');
        }
      });
      break;
    case 'mid':
      detail.find('option').each(function() {
        if (+$(this).val() < 5 && +$(this).val() > 2) {
          $(this).removeClass('hide');
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('hide');
        }
      });
      break;
    case 'high':
      detail.find('option').each(function() {
        if (+$(this).val() > 4) {
          $(this).removeClass('hide');
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('hide');
        }
      });
      break;
    case '':
      detail.find('option').show();
      detail.find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
      break;
  }

  detail.find('option:not(.hide):first').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="category">
          <option value="low">Low</option>
          <option value="mid">Mid</option>
          <option value="high">High</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="details">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="category">
          <option value="low">Low</option>
          <option value="mid">Mid</option>
          <option value="high">High</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="details">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Any difference between jquery hide() and css hide {display:none;} ? Like speed or something like that.

Comment: No there's no speed difference, the difference comes in the quality of code, using classes is more efficient than the inline style...

Comment: Isn't this what you're looking for @ghabriel ?